# How can I make Emacs Org-mode open links to sites in Google Chrome?

Tags: browser, emacs, google-chrome, org-mode

Google Chrome is set as the default browser. However, it opens links in Firefox, which is undesired.

How can I make [Org-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode) to open links in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Emacs 23.2 doesn't directly support Google Chrome, but it does support a "generic" browser, and something like this should work:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "chromium-browser")
```

You don't mention your OS, but if it's Windows or Mac, you can try:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-windows-browser)
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-macosx-browser)
```

And, if that doesn't work, there are other folks who have implemented `'browse-url-chrome`. Google turned up the following link:

- http://code.ohloh.net/search?s=browse-url-chrome&browser=Default

Comment: Another suggestion, if you're a Linux Gnome user, is to have emacs defer the decision to gnome:

(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic browse-url-generic-program  "gnome-open")

Comment: chromium-browser didn't work and neither did google-chrome, but `(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-macosx-browser)` worked.

Comment: I had to include full path, e.g.:
`(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")`

(Windows 7)

Comment: Futher to @MikeDalessio's comment, if you are using any linux desktop there is a good chance that using "xdg-open" instead of "gnome-open" will run the default browser configured for your desktop, so (setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic browse-url-generic-program "xdg-open")

Comment: Is there a way to use the $BROWSER environment variable?

Comment: The link is broken: *"Secure Connection Failed. An error occurred during a connection to code.ohloh.net. SSL peer has no certificate for the requested DNS name. Error code: SSL_ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT"*

Answer (score 11):

As [Trey suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506249/how-can-i-make-emacs-org-mode-open-links-to-sites-in-google-chrome/4506458#4506458), you can set it to a generic browser, but instead of "chromium-browser" use "google-chrome", like this:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "google-chrome")
```

That worked for me with Emacs 23.2 and Chrome 12.

Comment: This (unlike the above answers) works for me in Emacs 24.3 under Linux. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I have a similar problem (although the other way around: I wanted Emacs to open Firefox, but it opened Chromium).

I'm using [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin), but already had the problem with [Ubuntu 11.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_11.10_.28Oneiric_Ocelot.29) (Oneiric Ocelot). The solution below applies to Linux, maybe macOS (?), and probably not Windows.

Setting `browse-url-generic-program` as suggested in other answers didn't work for me. Note also that my default browser is generally Firefox: that's what most other applications are using to open a URL, including `xdg-open`. So I was surprised that Emacs would do otherwise.

I finally figured out that Emacs is using the `sensible-browser (1)` script. Looking at that script, I noticed that:

- it first looks at the `BROWSER` environment variable;
- else, it tries several other generic scripts, starting with `gnome-www-browser`

It so happens that, on my machine, `BROWSER` is not set, but `gnome-www-browser` is a script apparently put there by Chromium, and (naturally) running Chromium.

So, long story short: putting the following line

> export BROWSER=firefox # Or any browser of your choice

in your `.profile` may help if Emacs is not using the correct browser.

Comment: If you wish to eliminate chrome as default browser as a side effect of changing the emacs browser, you can do the following (I found it on bugs.launchpad.net):
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
  [then select your preferred browser from the menu]

Answer (score 5):

Setting the browser function is very easy using the GUI:

- In the menu, click `Options > Customize Emacs > Top-level customization Group`
- Click on the link `External` (Interfacing to external utilities.)
- Click on the link `Browse Url` (Use a web browser to look at a URL.)
- Click on the small triangle to the left of `Browse Url Browser Function`, this reveals a `Value Menu` button and some help text
- Click the `Value Menu` button
- Choose your preference from the displayed menu
- Move to the top of the buffer, click the button `Apply and Save` to save the change to your `~/.emacs` file

Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem when exporting org files to HTML. It would use Firefox instead of a Chromium browser. I fixed it by customizing `org-file-apps` (which for some reason had been set to open XHTML and HTML files with Firefox).

I now have an entry for extension `\.x?html?\'` with command set to the Lisp form: `(browse-url file)`

Answer (score 1):

I was on macOS and the `browse-url-default-macos-browser` did not work for me.

My solution was:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-chrome)
(setq browse-url-chrome-program "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For [ChrUbuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/), the `google-chrome` incantation as [given by Alan Turing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506249/how-can-i-make-emacs-org-mode-open-links-to-sites-in-google-chrome/6309985#6309985) works with Emacs 23.3.1, the default as of today. I suspect the chrubuntu configuration even when tickled to use chromium uses the wrong binary name.

Answer (score 0):

In **emacs** 28 (Fedora Linux) I just needed this

```lisp
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-chrome)
```