# Emacs: How to open ftp://... in Chrome? (http://... works)

Tags: emacs, org-mode

My `.emacs` contains

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-macosx-browser)
```

to open links in .org files via Chrome. The strange thing is that when I hit ftp://... links, they are opened in Firefox. All I found on this is [How to make emacs org-mode open links to sites in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506249/how-to-make-emacs-org-mode-open-links-to-sites-in-google-chrome) I checked all the options there, nothing helped.

Note: I'm working on Mac OS X 10.7.3 with Emacs 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `org-link-protocols` contains an entry for "ftp", the `browse-url` function should be invoked for this, in which case `browse-url-browser-function` would be used.

The latter *can* be a list mapping various URL patterns to different functions, but it looks like you're not using that ability.

`browse-url-default-macosx-browser` calls the `open` program, so I would have to assume that the problem is there, and thus external to Emacs.

You should be able to confirm that by running the shell command `open URL` for the various types of URL.

Comment: Indeed `open ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/` opens Firefox. I have to check how I can change that