# emacs (org-mode/helm-google) open links in eww?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, eww

I use emacs/ orgmode and helm-google.

When I open a page it opens it in google chrome. I would like it to open in eww. (ideally even have some way to have different hotkeys to open pages in either eww/chrome)

I tried to set var: browse-url-generic to 'eww', but no success.

I tried

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
  browse-url-generic-program "eww")
```

(as per [How to make emacs org-mode open links to sites in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506249/how-to-make-emacs-org-mode-open-links-to-sites-in-google-chrome)) but no success.

I asked the author of helm-google about this [in this post](https://github.com/steckerhalter/helm-google/issues/7), awaiting a reply?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'eww-browse-url)
```

should be what you're looking after.

Comment: The standard way to make customization is:
ask help about variable C-h v browse-url-browser-function --> choose 'ValueMenu' --> Choose the appropriate browser --> Chose 'Apply' --> Test it --> Choose 'Apply and Save'

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just set browse-url-browser-function to 'eww.

My suggestion would be to use the customize group and select eww (it is one of the choices in the menu for the browse-url-function. If that works, you can then look at it in the custom file to see how to set it manually. Once you have that, then you could try writing your own function which allows you to select the browser you want.

Answer (score 0):

Follow code snippet can open "http://" "https://" with `eww`only  in `org-mode`, instead of change default browser function to `eww`.

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'ol
  '(dolist (scheme '("http" "https"))
     (org-link-set-parameters
      scheme :follow (lambda (url arg) (eww (concat scheme ":" url) arg)))))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, with "org-link-open: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (url arg) (eww (concat scheme ":" url) arg)), 1".

Comment: I managed to have it working by adjusting handler lambda `(lambda (url) (eww (substring url 2))`