# How to make the link open by Chrome in emacs org-mode in mac?

Tags: google-chrome, emacs, org-mode

There is problem in my emacs: when I click a link in org-mode, it always prompt me:

> byte-code: Install w3m command in `exec-path' or set`w3m-command' variable correctly

It is very strange that the URL could be correctly opened by Chrome when I run `browse-url http://google.com` via `M-x`. However, when I click it, the error comes out!

Actually I don't wanna use w3m -- I wanna use Chrome to open the link.

I've searched for the answer, and found the following solution. But it does NOT work for me.

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "chromium-browser")
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-windows-browser)
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-macosx-browser)
```

-- from [How to make emacs org-mode open links to sites in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506249/how-to-make-emacs-org-mode-open-links-to-sites-in-google-chrome)

I've also tried to debug the `browse-url`, but failed to find the reason.

Now I've got a temporary rough solution -- overwrite the `browse-url` function:

```
(defun browse-url (url &rest args)
  "Browse url using outer browser"
  (interactive (browse-url-interactive-arg "URL: "))
  (call-process "open" nil nil nil url))
```

Are there any elegant solutions?

Comment: What happens if you use `(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-chromium)` and `(setq browse-url-chromium-program "chrome")`? (replace chrome with the name of the chrome executable, if different.

Comment: @juanleon It is still a message `byte-code: Install w3m command in exec-path or set-w3m-command variable correctly`. And I've tried to set a break point via `(debug-on-entry browse-url-chromium)`, but the debugger never stopped there.

Comment: did you try with `emacs -Q`?  Maybe some package is trying to override w3 browsing for you.

Comment: @juanleon Yes, of course. `emacs -Q` make this links' behavior normal. However, I've installed too many packages...

Comment: you need to do a binary search then... comment out half of the config, then check for behavior and comment/uncomment a quarter of the config, etc...

Comment: Thanks @juanleon. A binary searching will be helpful. I'll do it sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by customizing two variables:

`browse-url-chrome-program` to `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents//MacOS/Google Chrome`

`browse-url-browser-function` to `'browse-url-chrome`

For the first one, you might need a different path if Chrome is installed somewhere else.  I did need the full path.

Also, this will cause Emacs to use Chrome for all URLs, not just those in Org Mode.